# What is going on with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

Sorry I am new to Programming so I was unable to ask a more specific question. I find this code really confusing. I'm learning about callbacks.

```js
function add(x, y, callback) {
  callback(x + y)
}

function subtract(x, y, callback) {
  callback(x - y);
}

function multiply(x, y, callback) {
  callback(x * y);
}

function calculate(x, callback) {
  callback(x);
}

calculate(5, (n) => {
  add(n, 10, (n) => {
    subtract(n, 2, (n) => {
      multiply(n, 5, (n) => {
        console.log(n); // 65
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to at least explain to us what exactly gives you trouble understanding here. Please go read [ask]. We are not here for you to just drop code, and then expect us to explain what every single line of it does. You _need_ to be a bit more precise to begin with.

Comment: This is a weird example to show callbacks. Those should all be regular return functions.

Comment: @JavaScript seems like a simplified example of [Continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). You always have a "continuation" function that your current function has to call after finishing. Thus CPS gives you a chain of executions where each link only knows how to do one thing and then pass on the result without needing to know what the next part of the computation is. If you've seen how [middleware in Express is defined](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) it's an example of CPS where `next` function is the continuation.

Comment: @VLAZ: Looks more like a pointer-list-example (next, before, nil) to me. But yeah, I dont mind. Just strikes me like an odd usecase.

Comment: @JavaScript I don't know what this has to do with pointers.

Comment: @VLAZ: Fine by me. You dont have to.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all this script does is the following ((5 + 10) - 2) * 5. Which returns the sum of 65. It just does that with extensive use of callbacks.

All function you have has a callback, this means each function can call a another function if that function is defined,. side note: otherwise it gives an error.

```
function subtract(x, y, callback) {
  callback(x - y);
}
```

This function take in three values:
x equals A number
y equals The number that x will be minused with
callback = The function to run at the end

Let's just run that function and put in an anonymous function with a console.log

```
subtract(15, 2, function (x) {
  console.log(x);
  // x = 13
});
```

Let add another layer to that same function by calling it twice.

```
subtract(15, 2, function (x) {
  subtract(x, 2, function (x) {
    console.log(x);
    // x = 11
  });
});
```

That is how everything works, it is just nested functions over complicating basic math.

Answer (score -1):

This is a JS callback example:
In JS, just like a value one can pass a function to another function;

So, if you want to simplify what is going on here, in the calling part -

```js
var calculateVal = calculate(5); // result is 5
var addedVal = add(calculateVal, 10); // result is 15
var subtractVal = subtract(addedVal, 2); // result is 13
var multiplyVal = multiply(subtractVal, 5); // result is 65 ; your end resullt
```

Comment: The example is technically wrong, for the individual functions not returning values. Yet a nice breakdown nonetheless. Missing the final output/log.

Comment: Yeah, agree its not what is happening in reality, its just an alternative simplified view to see the complex call back example mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Lain you *can* [edit] to remove the snippet. I've done it now and I'd encourage you to also edit when you can make a post better immediately. Usually there is no need to wait if you can make a definite improvement.